# how to change request body from json to protobuf in postman script

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

how to change request body to protobuf in postman script?

I am testing an api endpoint that takes a protobuf msg as body,

in golang I would do something like

```
protodata, err = proto.Marshal(&protoStruct)
```

to convert the input json string to a marshalled proto message and post it with the request.
I am trying to do it in postman using scripts but I got an error importing the protobuf package

> There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
import { Protobuf } from 'google-protobuf';

const message = new Protobuf.Message();
message.set('msg', '{"command_code": "test_check"}');

const serialized = message.serialize();
pm.environment.set('request_body', serialized);
```

the input json is just

> {"command_code": "test_check"}

after go code executes, I usually gets the proto binary from json in the format

> "0A086669656C6431120676616C756531"

to post to the request url, I am trying to do the same with postman so that I can test it there

am I doing it wrong, is there built in support in postman to marshall json to protobuf?
I even tried printing out the binary in golang then try to use it as input for postman, but the binary printout only a representation of it that's why I thought of generating it in postman

> [10 184 1 10 123 10 32 32 34 102 ]

Answer (score 0):

I can answer part of your question.

The Postman Sandbox only supports certain libraries.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-external-libraries

However, can't you just send an normal grpc request?

https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/